# Trying to deploy a project in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I execute the

> docker-compose up -d

command

```
WARNING: The HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DOMAIN variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MYSQL_DATABASE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MYSQL_USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MYSQL_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DOMAIN_API variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.proxy.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
services.proxy.ports is invalid: Port ranges don't match in length
```

At work, did everything well.

OC:Manjaro 18

image: traefik:1.7

Comment: Please put your `docker-compose.yaml` file in your question for better helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due to you referencing environment variables in `docker-compose.yml` that are not present. All environment variables defined in the `.env` file are loaded in by default.

Make sure you have the `.env` file in the same directory as `docker-compose.yml` with all of your variables. In your case it may look like this:

```
HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT=80
HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT=443

HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT=3306

MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootroot
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=rootroot
MYSQL_DATABASE=dockertest
```

Or if your `docker-compose.yml` explicitly defines an `env_file` make sure it exists.

```
web:
  env_file:
    - ./.prod-env
```

E.g. with this example, there should be a file named `.prod-env` in the same directory as `docker-compose.yml`